# How to define pointcut for class initialization

Tags: aop, aspectj

I'm a newbie to AspectJ, and trying to understand joinpoint model
Now i have class like this

```
public class Account {
 private static Map<String, PaymentMethod> supportedPayments = new HashMap<>();
 static {
   supportedPayments.add("COD", new CodPaymentMethod());
   supportedPayments.add("ATM", new ATMPaymentMethod());
 }
}
```

as i read from AspectJ In Action, there is a way to define pointcut when class is intialization, but i could not find syntax.
Anyone help me?

This one does not work:

```
@Pointcut("initialization(com.jas.aop.bean.Payment"))
```

it say

```
ERROR] Syntax error on token "initialization(com.jas.aop.bean.Payment)", "name pattern" expected
/Users/admin/eclipse-workspace/aop/src/main/java/com/jas/aop/aspect/ClassInitializationAspect.java:9
@Pointcut("initialization(com.jas.aop.bean.Payment)")
```

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex , i edit question to correct as my try

Comment: This is a very handy and clear overview: https://soft.vub.ac.be/ajtraining/_media/quick5.pdf It contains the syntax and the patterns that go into the pointcuts and so on. F.e. see "TypePat"

Comment: @Hawk, that is actually a copy from the AspectJ documentation, see the [original here](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/quick5.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointcut has several problems:

- There is a missing closing parenthesis `)`.
- `initialization` intercepts constructors (i.e. object initialisation) rather than static class initialisation, which is not what you want and also would require a constructor pattern, not a class name pattern.
- If your aspect does not happen to be in the exact same package as the target class, you must use a fully qualified class name such as `my.package.Account` in order to make the pointcut match.

By the way, your code snippets are just pseudo code because a hash map does not have an `add` method, rather a `put` method. The sample class does not even compile. Don't just invent code when posting questions here. Make life easier for the people trying to help you.

Now here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something I always suggest you to specify in your question in order to help people reproduce your situation. I did it for you this time, this was your free shot. Next time, please do it yourself.

**Dependency classes used by the main class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface PaymentMethod {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ATMPaymentMethod implements PaymentMethod {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class CodPaymentMethod implements PaymentMethod {}
```

**Target class with driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Account {
  private static Map<String, PaymentMethod> supportedPayments = new HashMap<>();

  static {
    System.out.println("Static initialiser block");
    supportedPayments.put("COD", new CodPaymentMethod());
    supportedPayments.put("ATM", new ATMPaymentMethod());
  }

  public Account() {
    System.out.println("Creating account");
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing something");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Account().doSomething();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

The aspect shows both `initialization` and `staticinitialization` in order to show the difference in both syntax and functionality. You can find all of this explained with examples in the AspectJ manual, which I warmly recommend you to read.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class AccountAspect {
  @Before("initialization(de.scrum_master.app.Account.new(..))")
  public void interceptObjectInitialisation(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
  }

  @Before("staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Account)")
  public void interceptClassInitialisation(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Account.<clinit>)
Static initialiser block
initialization(de.scrum_master.app.Account())
Creating account
Doing something
```

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex
it work perfectly, sorry for my bad question looking, next time i will post real case that i met. About AspectJ manual, do you mean this page https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/index.html ?

Comment: Yes, but also the [programming guide](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/index.html) and the two quick reference guides found on the [documentation overview page](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/) for native syntax (which I prefer) and annotation-based syntax. There is also a [quick reference chapter in the programming guide](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/quick.html).